# Selenium Null pointer using Threadlocal and Extent Report

Tags: java, selenium, automation, thread-local, extentreports

I am trying to use extent report with thread local so I can run in parallel.
Running my classes in parallel.

Trying to execute the test in parallel, the problem is I am making some mistake in initialization so it failing before with null pointer exception.

**BaseClass**

```
public class BaseClass{

private static ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> testReport = new ThreadLocal<ExtentTest>();
public static ExtentReports extent;
@BeforeSuite
public void beforeSuite(ITestContext context) throws Exception {
     //Initiate Extent Report
        extent = ExtentReporter.createInstance(context, true);
}
@BeforeMethod
protected void setUpDriver(Method method, Object[] testArgs,ITestContext iTestContext) {

        //Start Test of Extent Report
        ExtentTest extentTest = extent.startTest((this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " :: " + method.getName()), method.getName());
        testReport.set(extentTest);

        testReport.get().assignCategory("", this.getClass().getSimpleName());

        //use extent report
        testReport.get().log(LogStatus.INFO, "Inside Base class - Before Method");
}
}
```

**ExtentReporter:**

```
public class ExtentReporter {

private static String reportName;
private static String reportPath;
private static File directory = new File(".");
private static String ReportRootFolder;

private static ExtentReports extent;

public ExtentReports getExtent() {

    return this.extent;
}

public static ExtentReports getInstance(ITestContext context, boolean replaceExisting) {

    try {
        if (extent == null)
            createInstance(context, replaceExisting);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return extent;
}


public static ExtentReports createInstance(ITestContext context, boolean replaceExisting) throws Exception {

    try {

        extent = new ExtentReports(reportPath, true);

        extent.loadConfig(new File(reportPath));
        extent.addSystemInfo("Environment", "QA");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return extent;
}

}
```

Comment: At which line you get NullPointerException? Please share the stack trace here.

Comment: just printing null

Comment: `reportPath` is not initialized. This could be the problem.

Comment: I've written multi-thread Extent Reports in the past with my own Extent Manager class and what I -think- might be a huge part of your problem is your extensive use of static in your declarations.  You might consider trying to remove most, if not all of the static references in your class.